# F# compiler plugins like haskell or

Tags: .net, f#

Is there a way to make compiler plugins for F# (thus, extending the language) like [Haskell](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/compiler-plugins.html) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins/)

Related:

- https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/477
- https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/448

Answer (score 0):

> It's just not something we're interested in pursuing. It's an extremely high-cost feature without a terrible amount of use for everyday F# programming.

https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/477#issuecomment-699526513